# Force column content to be `text-align: right`

Tags: html, css

What is the best way - if there is any at all, without using js -  to force all `td` that belong to one `col` to obtain properties that are specified in the `col`?

A simple

```
<col style='text-align:right' />
```

does not seem to have any impact on the underlying table cells content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style="float: right;"` in the tag which you want to align the right side.

Answer (score 2):

Using css and [`nth-child(column-index)`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```css
table tbody td:nth-child(2){
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, `<col>` has an [`align`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_col_align) attribute which isn't supported in HTML5 or any major browser.